# Please help debug a crash on UILabel (evict_glyph_entry_from_cache)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uilabel

I am facing a weird crash in "UILabel".The crash is initiated from drawRect of UILabel or CCLabelTTF). (I've already spent much time Googling this problem.) What could be causing th following code to crash?

I am using XCode SDK 4.0 and/or 4.1, cocos2d version 0.99.4, 0.99.5

**CODE:**

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,100,185,110)];
[label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:14]];

[label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
[label setNumberOfLines:50];
label.text = message;
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:81.0/255 blue:100.0/255 alpha:1]];

[self addSubview:label];
[label release]; label = nil;
```

**CRASH:**

```
Assertion failed: (cache->size >= g->size), function evict_glyph_entry_from_cache, file Fonts/CGFontCache.c, line 836.
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

#0  0x316b698c in __kill ()
#1  0x316b6982 in kill ()
#2  0x316b6974 in raise ()
#3  0x316cb620 in abort ()
#4  0x316b8f16 in __assert_rtn ()
#5  0x30f10d9e in evict_glyph_entry_from_cache ()
#6  0x30ed54e8 in expire_glyphs_nl ()
#7  0x30ed5494 in CGFontCacheUnlock ()
#8  0x30ed5008 in CGGlyphLockUnlock ()
#9  0x31e3a5e4 in ripc_RenderGlyphs ()
#10 0x31e42a66 in ripc_DrawGlyphs ()
#11 0x30ed0714 in CGContextDelegateDrawGlyphs ()
#12 0x30ed06c8 in draw_glyphs ()
#13 0x30ed025a in CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances ()
#14 0x311381f0 in WebCore::Font::drawGlyphs ()
#15 0x31137e42 in WebCore::Font::drawGlyphBuffer ()
#16 0x31137c76 in WebCore::Font::drawSimpleText ()
#17 0x31137ad2 in WebCore::Font::drawText ()
#18 0x31137a5e in drawAtPoint ()
#19 0x3117fdd4 in -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) _web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:measureOnly:] ()
#20 0x31180c50 in -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) _web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:] ()
#21 0x325ca46c in -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:] ()
#22 0x325ca40a in -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:lineSpacing:] ()
#23 0x325cb414 in -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] ()
#24 0x325cadf2 in -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] ()
#25 0x325cadaa in -[UILabel drawRect:] ()
#26 0x325c98e8 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] ()
#27 0x30c6b308 in -[CALayer drawInContext:] ()
#28 0x30c6b190 in backing_callback ()
#29 0x30c6acb6 in CABackingStoreUpdate ()
#30 0x30c6a47e in -[CALayer _display] ()
#31 0x30c6a1ce in -[CALayer display] ()
#32 0x30c6a14a in CALayerDisplayIfNeeded ()
#33 0x30c6994a in CA::Context::commit_transaction ()
#34 0x30c696a8 in CA::Transaction::commit ()
#35 0x30c6f030 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback ()
#36 0x33519b56 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#37 0x33560a38 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#38 0x3356035c in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#39 0x30248b32 in GSEventRunModal ()
#40 0x30248bde in GSEventRun ()
#41 0x3259776e in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#42 0x32596472 in UIApplicationMain ()
#43 0x0000288e in main (argc=1, argv=0x2ffff618) at /Users/ahsan/Public/Drop Box/today1/main.m:13
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the font name is `@"MarkerFelt-Thin"`. Try that.

**Edit:** There is also a `@"MarkerFelt-Wide"`.

Comment: I have done what you said. After changing the font name from "family name" i.e. Marker Felt to "font name" i.e. MarkerFelt-Thin, the percentage of crash has reduced but it still comes randomly. DOes it has to do anything with memory or processing? I am too confused, dont know what todo?

Answer (score 1):

It is crashing because you  need to enter the correct font name, or else UIKit will try to load non-existent fonts. So, you should check your font name. Try using `@"MarkerFelt"` (no space instead of `@"Marker Felt"`, with the space).

If you are not sure of what the value should be, there are several apps on the app store that can get the list of currently available fonts for you. You can also use [this code snippet](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2008/10/05/snippet-available-uifonts/) to log the font names to the console:

```
   // Get all the fonts on the system
NSArray *familyNames = [UIFont familyNames];
for( NSString *familyName in familyNames ){
    printf( "Family: %s \n", [familyName UTF8String] );
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName];
    for( NSString *fontName in fontNames ){
        printf( "\tFont: %s \n", [fontName UTF8String] );
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can also have a look at [this post](http://blog.mro.name/2010/08/uilabel-with-a-custom-cgfont/) and see if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir, but there is no problem in the font. It works fine much of the time, but crashes randomly sometimes... I also have tried system font but the problem persists... The actual crash occurs in UIStringDrawing class of apple. Both UILabel(UIKit) and CClabel(CCLabel) eventually uses UIStringDrawing.

Comment: @user533917 can you please add some more context? (Describe your cocos2d a little more, perhaps some more code samples.)

Comment: This is a code snippet of my custom alert inherited from UIView, I have animated it. The label is set in the init method call, there is not much i am doing in that other than calling start animations in the end. Can this be linked in anyway to the MEMORY issues or Project Settings? currently I have used these settings in my project: Project Settings -> Standard (armv6 armv7), Target Settings -> Standard (armv6 armv7), Compile for thumb (armv7)

Comment: @user533917 - Your project settings are fine. To check for Memory issues, use "Build and Analyze" from the `Build` menu. Also, since you are using cocos2d, the problem could lie there. It's looks unlikely from your code, but Cocos2d could be causing a conflict.

Comment: @user533917 - You should also try `[label setText:@"text"]` instead of `label.text`.

Comment: @user533917 - Also, confirm that you are calling the superclass' initialization function inside of your init method.

Comment: I have done all what you said. After changing the font name from "family name" i.e. Marker Felt to "font name" i.e. MarkerFelt-Thin, the percentage of crash has reduced but it still comes randomly. DOes it has to do anything with memory or processing? I am too confused, dont know what todo?

Comment: one more thing, this crash mostly comes on iOS 3.1.3 on NSString drawing... I have ran Leaks, Allocations, Clang and other tools with no success. The Allocations show a total stable memory upto 5MB... dont know what to do :(

Answer (score 0):

> One thing worth mentioning is that the application does heavy processing

This is also my observation! Heavy load crashes my app. At this moment I believe that this problem is the framework bug and should be reported. https://bugreport.apple.com

My crash comes when updating CCLabelTTF (Cocos2D 0.99.5)

```
Assertion failed: (cache->size >= g->size), function evict_glyph_entry_from_cache, file Fonts/CGFontCache.c, line 836.

Program received signal: “SIGABRT”.

This is the trace:

#0  0x304a0b2c in __kill ()
#1  0x304a0b20 in kill ()
#2  0x304a0b14 in raise ()
#3  0x304b7e3a in abort ()
#4  0x304a42f2 in __assert_rtn ()
#5  0x30f33648 in evict_glyph_entry_from_cache ()
#6  0x30ee5fc0 in expire_glyphs_nl ()
#7  0x30ee5f50 in CGFontCacheUnlock ()
#8  0x30ee5868 in CGGlyphLockUnlock ()
#9  0x33191ce0 in ripc_RenderGlyphs ()
#10 0x3319c9e0 in ripc_DrawGlyphs ()
#11 0x30edf7b0 in draw_glyphs ()
#12 0x30edf25c in CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances ()
#13 0x3109e010 in WebCore::Font::drawGlyphs ()
#14 0x3109dabc in WebCore::Font::drawGlyphBuffer ()
#15 0x3109d76c in WebCore::Font::drawSimpleText ()
#16 0x3109d5c8 in WebCore::Font::drawText ()
#17 0x3109d504 in drawAtPoint ()
#18 0x31101bd4 in -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) _web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:measureOnly:] ()
#19 0x31103a78 in -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) _web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:] ()
#20 0x331fcb60 in -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:] ()
#21 0x332f5184 in -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:] ()

#22 0x002f04a4 in -[CCTexture2D(Text) initWithString:dimensions:alignment:font:] (self=0x64e240, _cmd=0x455973, string=0x677040, dimensions={width = 28, height = 24}, alignment=UITextAlignmentCenter, uifont=0x649690) at /Users/SG/Documents/code/AlgWin/libs/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:405
#23 0x002f07a4 in -[CCTexture2D(Text) initWithString:fontName:fontSize:] (self=0x64e240, _cmd=0x44d3f4, string=0x677040, name=0x668990, size=20) at /Users/SG/Documents/code/AlgWin/libs/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:505
#24 0x002a8988 in -[CCLabelTTF setString:] (self=0x649490, _cmd=0x33f490cc, str=0x677040) at /Users/SG/Documents/code/AlgWin/libs/cocos2d/CCLabelTTF.m:91
```

Observe that 22 lines are identical to yours.

I will try to come with the code to reproduce the crash. Maybe just an infinite loop will be enough.